# How to generate a comfortable form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, command-line-interface

I want to generate a form that is comfortable to look using JavaScript like this
[image]

However, I tried `console.table` to do that, but it actually generated a bad form.
How I can resolve this issue?

```
export function showNodeVersion(metadata: Metadata[]): void {
    const current = getCurrent(metadata).slice(0, 9);
    const lts = getLTS(metadata).slice(0, 9);
    const craft = {
        Current: current.map(m => {
            return m.version;
        }),
        LTS: lts.map(m => {
            return m.version;
        })
    }
    console.table(craft)
}
```

[image]

Comment: I have included it

Comment: if you don't want it horizontal (which doesn't fit on your terminal screen), use an array of objects not an object of arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.table` can produce a table somewhat like the desired output shown, but with some caveats:

- The data would need to be provided as an array of objects,
- Column headers can be provided as an array using the second parameter of `console.log`,
- An extra column appears on the left showing array index vales.
- If used in a client-side browser, column content appears to be provided in a variable width font (not monospace) with left justification.

Copy and past the following into your browser console and press enter to see the output (Code Snippets don't appear to support `console.table`).

```
// 4 rows of dummy data:

const sep = /,\s*/;
const CURRENT = "21.4.0,  21.3.0, 21.2.0,  21.1.0"  .split(sep); 
const LTS =     "20.10.0, 20.9.0, 18.19.0, 18.18.2" .split(sep);

const table = [];
const nRows = 4;
for( let i = 0; i < nRows; ++ i) {
  table.push( {CURRENT: CURRENT[i], LTS: LTS[i]})
}

console.table( table, ["CURRENT", "LTS"]);
```

If the caveats are acceptable you would still need to create the table data for the four columns shown in the post's desired output.

Comment: It looks like the OP is using node.js, not the browser console. At least your caveat about monospace does not seem to apply